# Unable to connect to wireless network following upgrade to 15.04

Tags: wireless

I upgraded my Dell Inspiron 7547 from Ubuntu 14.10 to Ubuntu 15.04 today, and I am now unable to connect to wireless networks.

I can see the wireless connection I am trying to connect to, but I am unable to connect. The connection times out without presenting an error message. First I tried forgetting the network and putting the information back in manually. I then tried disabling the wireless security on the router (Linksys E900) and reconnecting and had the same issue. I also tried connecting to a WiFi hotspot from my phone and had the same issue. The wireless connection from the router works fine on Windows 8.1 and my other wireless devices.

Any advice on what I should try next? What additional information can I provide to help?

Per comment, here is the output from running the wireless script: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10875310/

Comment: Just fyi, the version number is the date. 15 means 2015 and 04 means April. 15.4 is not the standard way it's written. Info from these [wireless scripts](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108) can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks, Grant. I updated the version number and posted the results of running the wireless scripts.

Comment: Try deleting all connection settings through gui or manually in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections folder. Restart network manager and try to reconnect

Comment: Lots more data to work from to help solve your issue! These two lines look interesting and might relate to your issue.

`parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)`

Comment: @Serg That didn't seem to work. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: No problem ! that the common thing to try first

Comment: @GrantBowman I'm relatively new to Linux and programming, so I don't fully understand what makes those statements interesting. I have a high-level understanding of the power management, but I'm unfamiliar with `debug an ASSERT in INIT fw`, as I have not had much exposure to firmware yet. Any suggestions on additional reading? Thanks again for taking the time time to help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have been having similar issues (same wireless card). Here is what I did to fix it:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Add `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to file, save, and close. Then:

```
sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi 
sudo modprobe iwlmvm iwlwifi 
sudo service network-manager restart
```

This will inactivate Wireless N so network speed may be affected.

If that doesn't work undo what you did by:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

and delete the last line (`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`) and everything will be back to the way it was before.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks so much! I'm not terribly concerned about the speed. What made you think to disable the Wireless N?

Comment: Also, there's a typo in the last bit of code. Should be 'modprobe.d'.

Comment: Seems to be the common fix for intel chipsets, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, thanks for the catch. Should be good now (stupid dyslexia). As for the reason why, I've had issues in the past with intel wifi chips and this has fixed my issues in the past. Sorry that I cant provide a more technical answer.

Answer (score 1):

Evan's solution wasn't working. But, I have fixed the wifi issue by upgrading my linux kernel to 4.x as mentioned in the below post - [Install Linux Kernel 4.0.3](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/05/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-0-3-in-linux.html)

Comment: Yeah this one worked. Fresh 15.04 installation on Intel i5