# wireless doesn't work after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: wireless, upgrade, mouse, 15.04

I know this was already answered by Evan T at [Unable to connect to wireless network following upgrade to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613065/unable-to-connect-to-wireless-network-following-upgrade-to-15-04), however, I am having some trouble doing all the indicated steps: after `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`, I receive the message:

```
(gedit: 1627): Gtk-Warning **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

After typing "sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi" I received another two error messages:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlmvm is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwifi is not currently loaded
```

Also, I don't know if this is related to the wireless internet problem, but the laptop doesn't recognise the mouse (in any USB port, the mouse is wireless).
Thank you!

Comment: Unless you are also using a laptop with an **Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 3160** [8086:8470] chipset (which uses the **iwlwifi** driver), then the steps given are NOT going to do much for you. ***Start by identifying the WiFi chipset.*** eg. output from **`lsusb`**, or  **`lspci -nn`**

Comment: I'm not sure which is the chipset I am looking for, soI will list below theones I founf for my laptop: HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller. Is this what we are looking for?

Comment: It's a Lenovo B590 running with an Intel Core I3

Comment: In the output I received several 4digit codes, but "Broadcom" appeared nowhere in all the output.

Comment: I also read the info in the link you indicated, but I can't mive further wirhout that 4 digit Broadcom code...

Comment: Check output of: **`lspci -vnn | grep Network`**

Comment: Yeees! Finaly! :D Intel Corp. Centrino Wireless-N 2330 [8086:0888] (rev c4)

Comment: Unfortunately this Broadcom ID does not appear in the list that indicates what command you should run accordingly.

Comment: What does `rfkill list all` show?

Comment: Please check.  Is it in fact? Intel **Centrino Wireless-N 2230**

Comment: rfkill list all does nit show anything

Comment: Yes david6, sorry for the typo, you are right.

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: I receive an Error message: ../libid/libkmos-module.c:816 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name=`iwlwifi`. And also a amother erroe message stating "could not insert 'iwlwifi': Funtion not implemented"

Answer (score 0):

This looks simple enough.

Looking at: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

*Download driver, copy to correct location, etc.*

--

That said, it should already work in **15.04** ..

Comment: :( I downloaded the driver for my chipset in my phone, since I cannot use the internet with the laptop. After connecting the phone to the laptop with a usb cable, it seems that the laptop has any reaction to it. If it's only the wireless rhat is not working, shouldn't I be able to have cable internet at least? Sorry if my question seems silly, but I don't knoq much on programing ..

Comment: ***Android or iPhone ?*** For iPhone you may need an app. to tether. For Android, you need to enable 'USB tethering'.

Comment: It is Android, however it was solved meanwhile. It is good to know anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like backports might be the easiest way to fix this

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/03/13/backports-20150313.tar.xz
tar xvfJ backports-20150313.tar.xz
cd backports-20150313
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: I let the internet cable plugged all day and run from time to time the software updater and somehow the system managed to install the necesary updates left and then asked the reboot. :) And now it works - both the internet and the mouse. (Also the sound was affected, the players were working but the songs were "mute".) I'm sorry we could not track the initial cause of all this, but I am very glad that everything works ok now. Thank you all for the answers and comments.

Comment: I am thinking you somehow got a corrupt kernel and that is why iwlwifi was not found.  You must have downloaded a newer kernel in an update and that is why it works now